# root filesystem extraction failed with singularity on circleci

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

I created a [test repo](https://github.com/Ulthran/test-containerize) to play around with containerization of snakemake workflows. I've got the workflow working locally and on the cluster (slurm) but I can't get it working in circleci. I keep getting:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Pulling singularity image docker://*********/test-containerize:0.0.0.
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Conda environments: ignored
Job stats:
job         count    min threads    max threads
--------  -------  -------------  -------------
all             1              1              1
all_TEST        1              1              1
total           2              1              1

Select jobs to execute...

[Mon Dec 19 19:42:03 2022]
rule all_TEST:
    input: test.txt
    output: output.txt
    jobid: 1
    reason: Missing output files: output.txt
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

Activating singularity image /home/circleci/project/.snakemake/singularity/4f64024d9840ccf1a4d8836c5edc6aa5.simg
INFO:    Converting SIF file to temporary sandbox...
FATAL:   while extracting /home/circleci/project/.snakemake/singularity/4f64024d9840ccf1a4d8836c5edc6aa5.simg: root filesystem extraction failed: extract command failed: ERROR  : Failed to set mount propagation: Operation not permitted
: exit status 1
[Mon Dec 19 19:42:03 2022]
Error in rule all_TEST:
    jobid: 1
    input: test.txt
    output: output.txt
    conda-env: /home/circleci/project/.snakemake/conda/cc6395ec670d10af0374c53e5653fb76_
    shell:
        cat test.txt > output.txt
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2022-12-19T194136.569293.snakemake.log

Exited with code exit status 1
```

I don't have enough experience with containers to know what's going wrong here, seems like maybe a permissions issue, except I'm also getting the same error locally with a more complicated workflow that I tried to set up containerization for. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you somehow test if the container can be extracted and setup outside of snakemake? To make sure the container itself is working fine.

Comment: Yea I'm able to run this workflow locally with `--use-singularity` but seemingly the same command on circleci's runner gets this error. Is there something more I should be testing by extracting it outside of snakemake?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the specifics of circleci :/ . It was just an idea to test it locally with the singularity container. From your post I didn't understand that you already have it locally running with singularity.